# Filter nested data from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
dict = {
        'user_1': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
        'user_2': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
        'user_3': {'role': 1, 'perm': 4},
        'user_4': {'role': 1, 'perm': 7},
        'user_5': {'role': 3, 'perm': 5}
    }
```

How can I filter to pick up only keys with:

Repeated roles and permissions:

```
repeated_role_perm = {
        'user_1': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
        'user_2': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
    }
```

Roles repeated but without repeated permissions:

```
only_role_repeated = {
      'user_3': {'role': 1, 'perm': 4},
      'user_4': {'role': 1, 'perm': 7},
}
```

The leftovers:

```
leftovers = {
 'user_5': {'role': 3, 'perm': 5}
}
```

I was able to short the data with the code:

```
shorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(list.items(), key=lambda x: (operator.getitem(x[1], 'role'), operator.getitem(x[1], 'perm'))))
```

But that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: Can you give us more background on what you tried?

Comment: I tried to organize the data and I got, but that's not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try a function?

```
 my_dict = {
    'user_1': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
    'user_2': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
    'user_3': {'role': 1, 'perm': 4},
    'user_4': {'role': 1, 'perm': 7},
    'user_5': {'role': 3, 'perm': 5}
}

 def filter_dict(role,perm,dic):
      filtered = {}
      users = [k for k in dic.keys() if dic[k]['role'] == int(role) and 
      dic[k]['perm'] == int(perm)]
      for user in users:
           filtered[user] = dic[user]
 return filtered
```

This function returns,

```
 filter_dict(1,5,my_dict)
 {'user_1': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5}, 'user_2': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You kinda want to turn the whole thing inside out as you build an index.  Then you can use the index to construct the dictionaries you want:

```
import json

data = {
        'user_1': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
        'user_2': {'role': 1, 'perm': 5},
        'user_3': {'role': 1, 'perm': 4},
        'user_4': {'role': 1, 'perm': 7},
        'user_5': {'role': 3, 'perm': 5}
    }

# Build an index
index = {}
for (user, v) in data.items():
    role = v['role']
    perm = v['perm']
    if role not in index:
        index[role] = {}
    if perm not in index[role]:
        index[role][perm] = []
    index[role][perm].append({user:v})

# Dump the index
# print(json.dumps(index, indent=4))

# Define our target dictionaries
repeated_role_perm = {}
only_role_repeated = {}
leftovers = {}

# Walk our index, putting each leaf into the right target dictionary
for role in index:
    perms = index[role]
    target = leftovers
    for perm in perms:
        users = index[role][perm]
        if len(perms) > 1:
            if len(users) > 1:
                target = repeated_role_perm
            else:
                target = only_role_repeated
        for userdict in users:
            target.update(userdict)

# Print the results
print('repeated_role_perm = ' + json.dumps(repeated_role_perm, indent=4))
print()
print('only_role_repeated = ' + json.dumps(only_role_repeated, indent=4))
print()
print('leftovers = ' + json.dumps(leftovers, indent=4))
```

Result:

```
repeated_role_perm = {
    "user_1": {
        "role": 1,
        "perm": 5
    },
    "user_2": {
        "role": 1,
        "perm": 5
    }
}

only_role_repeated = {
    "user_3": {
        "role": 1,
        "perm": 4
    },
    "user_4": {
        "role": 1,
        "perm": 7
    }
}

leftovers = {
    "user_5": {
        "role": 3,
        "perm": 5
    }
}
```